# How to get slider value on click of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a range-slider which has two ranges. I want to get the value of this slider in my javascript.

Here is what I have done:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  
  $(function() {

 $("#find_match").click(function(){

      alert($('#amount').val(ui.values[ 0 ]));
      
  });  
  
    $(function() {
      $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 20,
        max: 60,
        values: [ 20, 30 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
      });
      $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
                         " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
</script>


<body>
    <label for="amount">
        Age range:
    </label>
 <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
 <div id="slider-range"></div>
        <button id="find_match">Search matches </button>
</body>
```

In the `onclick()` I have done this; however it doesn't work out.

It says "ui is not defined" in the above code.
I want the value of above slider on a button click. How to do it?

Note: Slider is not showing up.

Comment: Can you post a complete example and a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this in the onclick function:

```
var minAge = $('#amount').val();
```

From the [documentation of .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/): if presented with no arguments, `.val()` returns the value of the item. If presented with one argument, `.val(value)` sets the value of the item to the argument you provided.

Comment: I get both of my values using this

Comment: It helped me.. I got the answer using this;

  var sliderVal = $('#amount').val();
  var res =sliderVal.split("-");

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the standard jquery ui slider.

The API says http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-values you just have to call:

```
 $("#find_match").click(function(){
    var minAge = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "option", "values" )[0];
});
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kbrqb/337/

Comment: Maybe just remove the "[0]" and use console.log to see what's the return value. 
The ui variable is the instance of the slider object. So you should interact with this instance only.

Comment: Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Comment: FYI ... I have slider defined in <script> of my index.php and I have another js file where I am trying to access it.

Comment: I have two files. One containing the js contents of onclick() and the other containing the slider(). If I take your code,, it gives " Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'  "

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the value of `#slider-range`, you could use `attr()`:

```
$("div").attr("$slider-range");
```

Comment: I have got a range slider which has two end-points. I am trying to get these two values in my javascript file; 

However, here is the problem: I have my php file where I have defined my slider to get the input from the user. 

I have a js file where which am using to do some ajax call. I am trying to access the slider values in this file. It shows weird errors like .. " Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option "

Comment: To be clear, at this point, you have the two values with JS, however, those values aren't being processed correctly with PHP. Is this correct? If so, we can only help PHP related issues with the PHP code.

Comment: Issue solved. I am getting the values now. However, I am getting the values like this..

if I select the range 20 and 30 then .. $("amount").val() I get 20-30

Comment: @Nevermore Like what?